# How to say 'that' as a conjunction as in "I'm pleased that it is friday"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary

I see this use of 'that' in English sentences all the time connecting subordinate clauses and such. I was wondering how'd you say something like "I'm pleased that it is Friday" or "He told me that it will be easy" in latin.

I'm unsure if it uses ut/subjunctive or its unnecessary in this form or something else

Answer (score 7):

In general, you cannot translate that one word in English with one word in Latin in all scenarios. Subordination in many languages tend to be very idiomatic, and both English and Latin are no different in that regard. (Think about: why "that" at all?)

Depending on the introductory verb, you typically wouldn't translate it at all. Instead, you use would use the infinitive + accusative construction, what's called [indirect statement](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/declamatory-sentences-indirect-discourse).

There are many rules around this, dictating e.g. [how the tenses work](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/tenses-infinitive-indirect-discourse), so you can't do a simple one-to-one with English.

So, for your example sentence, "I'm glad that it's *X*", you would use *placere* in the impersonal, the subject goes into the dative, and then you'd have an indirect sentence, just like in this example from Cicero's letters:

> Mihi placet, si tibi videtur, te ad eum scribere...
> I'm glad (lit. "it is pleasing to me), if it seems good to you, **that** you write to him...

---

Other possibilities that eventually took over Latin in later eras are *quod* and *quia* or *quoniam*. The former seemed in earlier Latin to mean more "the fact that" or otherwise used [when introducing a factual statement](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/indicative-quod), while the latter originally meant "since" or "because", but by later Latin (and in earlier, uneducated speech), they could both be used to simply introduce an indirect statement. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_indirect_speech) has a quick breakdown.

So using *gaudeo* (thanks to Cerberus for the suggestion), you could do *gaudeo quod...*, but in Classical Latin would mean something along the lines of "I rejoice in the fact that...", which is only a short hop away from "I'm glad that...".

Comment: How would you phrase "I'm glad it's Friday" using an ACI? Or would you use a causal solution instead? I agree with the answer, but I'm not sure what it entails for the specific example sentence.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I'm not sure about "it's Friday", but I took these as illustrative examples, rather than a desire to know the specifics of these examples. I gave a concrete example though using the construction in the title.

Comment: This answer is of course correct, but I believe it so happens that (personal) verbs expressing an emotion often do so by means of a *quod* clause, like *gaudeo quod* (though an a.c.i. is also possible): "I am glad (about the fact) that". This may be where Mediaeval Latin got its general use of *quod* for the a.c.i. In addition, some verbs (sometimes or normally) use *ut* "that" instead of an a.c.i., like various verbs of asking/demanding, happening: *peto ut, accidit ut*. And of course verbs of fear or prohibition usually use *ne* for "that".

Comment: @Cerberus I edited it some more. I think the ut clauses after words like *peto* are often considered purpose clauses. You can also have *fac ut*. Simply put, there's no one single way to translate that word. One has to do the heavy lifting of actually learning the grammar *in toto*.

Comment: Thanks for this breakdown, it makes a lot of sense. There is a lot about languages that is generally idiomatic that I don't notice until I look between them, I find it pretty interesting. I find myself wanting to write subordinate clauses in sentences often and was wondering what that would look like in Latin, this is a great help.

Comment: @Cerberus, to add the discussion. Before edit, I actually started writing an answer discuss this issue where *ut* is an idiomatic choice. like *spero ut* or *vellim ut* or the "impersonal" as  *evenit ut* or *fit ut*. However, as cmw, I feel it is closer to purpose clause or simply a correlative to sometime implied *id* or *hoc* (see elusive example: ["lex ut"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14892/does-ita-have-two-roles-part-of-construction-ut-ita-functioning-as-an-i/14894#14894).) *placere ut* is attested but seems only as propose ("resolved to" as opposed to "pleased that")

Comment: @cmw: Is it, "mihi placet nunc diem Veneris esse."? (I've avoided using "hodie" = "on this day").

Comment: @Cerberus: Is it: "gaudeo diem Veneris adesse."? Alternatively, "gaudeo quod dies Veneris adest."?

Comment: @tony: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Factual *quod* after verba affectus is a regular occurrence, and A & G (on the page you linked) translate *gaudeo quod* as "I am glad that." I believe any reservations around this usage (or it's classical character) are unnecessary.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I was speaking more to its historical development. I wasn't limiting this to certain types of verbs because that would be taking the OP too literally. I wasn't aiming at a translation, but to explain that in general you wouldn't use *quod* to translate "that" in any given indirect statement, not only verbs of feeling.

Comment: (In other words, I'm not disagreeing, just making a different point.)