# How would you translate "to" in "I am happy to still be a child." or "You are lucky to be alive."?

Tags: syntax, infinitive

I know that English infinitives often do not correspond to Latin infinitives (for example, you cannot grammatically translate "*Here to save the day.*" as "*Hic servare diem.*"), and I suppose that is also the case in sentences such as "*I am happy to still be a child.*" or "*You are lucky to be alive.*". So, how would you translate such sentences to Latin?

Comment: Are you learning Latin formally? Have you yet to come across an indirect statement?

Comment: People always worry about the wrong things. The real difficulty in "I am happy to still be a child" is how to translate "child" :-)

Comment: @cmw Are you telling me that should be translated as indirect speech, with accusative with infinitive? "*Felix sum me etiamnunc liberum esse.*"? I've studied Latin for two years in high-school.

Comment: In "*happy to still be a child*", "to" isn't really a word by itself that can be translated. This is an example of where the "don't split an infinitive" rule really should be applied: "*happy to be still a child*", with "to be" treated as a single word, the infinitive form of the verb.

Comment: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/20828/how-to-say-that-as-a-conjunction-as-in-im-pleased-that-it-is-friday/

Comment: In the given examples, my first intuition would be to use *quod*, when the main predicate expresses an emotion/sentiment about / caused by some fact.

Comment: Obviously you want to get a t(o) in there, so *fēlīcitātem* rather than *felix*. Sounds like Polandball a bit, I am *of happy* to see you :D